What is a safe paint to use in an aquarium?
I am building a wooden lid for my tank. I want to paint the interior that may touch the water white. I wish to stain and paint the rest clear. What paint is safe to do this?

I have no experience with this exact question, but I would start to research at baby-safe paints. They need to be non toxic and the baby need to be not able to "lick" it from the surface.

if you search for:food safe paint for wood,you will find many products and some of them are likely to be safe for fish tanks if you look at the product pages.
